# Viual studio installer not updating

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, updates

So I want to update my installer.

When I click the update button (as seen on the picture bellow).
And then it makes me confirm that I understand the law stuff, takes me 
through
green bar, says please wait for a few seconds, and then we 're back on the
"please update visual studio installer" screen.
    I am using windows 10, I'm not sure if that'll help but here you have it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're starting the installer as administrator and you may need to disable your proxy.